# How to make rust send a flush system call when writing data?

Tags: linux, rust, flush, fuse

We know that `Write::flush` for on-disk file is actually a no-op.
And `BufWriter::flush` also wont send `flush` system call in Linux.
So, how to do?

Btw, I don't want to call `mem::drop(file)`

Because I want to write to mounted path with blobfuse.
Blobfuse may be for the sake of perf, so the upload file is only available when close file. Refer: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-fuse/blob/master/blobfuse/fileapis.cpp#L346

Comment: Not sure what you're asking about, `File::write` directly writes to the file, so there is no need for `flush` to do anything. Are you maybe asking how to [`sync_data`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.sync_data) or `sync_all`?

Comment: There is no flush system call in Linux.

Comment: As others have said, `File` is unbuffered, so flushing it simply doesn't make sense - each `write()` goes directly to the OS, there is no intermediate buffer to flush. If your actual problem is that "upload file is only available when close file", in that case you might have to call `mem::drop()` indeed. Why don't you want to do that?